# Determining the quotient of the symmetric group with the even permutations group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

> Determine the group of $S_n/A_n$ up to isomorphism

I am not sure what it is isomorphic to. I may also be misinterpreting precisely what this problem is asking. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Hint: How many elements does $S_n/A_n$ have?

Comment: @nbritten ah so the order of the quotient group is 2, so it is only isomorphic to $Z_2$?

Comment: $S_n$ has $n!$ elements and $A_n$ has $n!/2$ elements, so $S_n/A_n$ should have $2$ elements. Now, all groups with $2$ elements are isomorphic to $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$.

Comment: @Math1000 a bit of back pedalling, but why is this not the group of odd permutations? I understand that the order makes it obvious, but writing out the definition, I am not sure why this is the case.

Comment: Well, what are the elements of $S_n/A_n$? They are the cosets of...?

Comment: It is $\{\sigma + A_n | \sigma \in A_n\}$. So you are multiplying an even cycle by some arbitrary cycle in $S_n$. If $\sigma$ is even, then it is identity? Not sure if even cycle times an even cycle is also even. One case will be identity, and the other will be all odd permutations no?

Comment: @hkj447 Even cycle times even cycle is even. The definition of even permutation is that $\sigma$ is even if whenever you write $\sigma$ as a product of transpositions, $\sigma = \sigma_1 \cdots \sigma _n$, then $n$ is even. Can you see why the product of two even permutations is even?

Comment: @hkj447 Anyway this is too specific. In general, if you have a group $G$ with a subgroup $H$, and you take an $h \in H$, then $hH = H$, and if you take a $g$ outside of $H$, then $gH \not = H$, but is rather a coset of $H$. ($H$ is a coset of itself too).